# Can I get involuntarily bumped from a flight even though I already have a boarding pass with an assigned seat?

Tags: united-airlines, missed-flights, flight-status

I am at Newark airport right now, waiting to board a flight to MCO (Orlando, FL) with United Airlines.

They are announcing that the flight is overbooked by 7 passengers and that they need volunteers to be bumped from the flight for a (measly) 150$ compensation.

I **cannot** afford to be bumped since I have a cruise tomorrow morning and they obviously won't wait for me...

I have checked in for the flight online and received my boarding pass **with an assigned seat**.  Furthermore, (if that matters) I'm a frequent flyer for the airline. I have booked this ticket 6 months ago.

So, I ask you, can they just bump me in these circumstances?

Comment: I realized it's a duplicate and closed it.